# Find all realted matched docs in an array of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema model that have a field name *tags* , and it is an array of strings to store some tags in it for each document. I want something for example if I have an array of tags like ["test", "testimonials", "test Doc"] tags in it, when i search for test, it returns all documents with tags that they are testimonials or test doc , it should be work for example like wildcards (test*) .... can anyone help ?

this is the model

```
tags: {
  type: [
    {
      type: String,
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd tweak the Schema if possible. Your schema could be changed to this:

```
tags: [String]
```

This also just means an array of strings.  You don't need to always need to use/specify the `type` key unless you're planning to add more fields to the tag schema, but it doesn't look like it from the question.

You can do the following to select all documents with a specific tag.  Since I don't know what the name of your model is, I'll just call it "Model".

```
await Model.find({ tags: "tagName" })
```

OR

```
await Model.find({ tags: { $elemMatch: { someKey: someValue } } })
```

The later is only if you have other mongodb documents inside the array.  Since you only have strings in the array, use the first method.

Comment: thanks for your replay . I know the solution you said to me but the problem is that I have some seperate documents that have tags like "test", "test2", "testtest". and I want to when I query to find "test" tags , it returns the other tags that has same values as test like "test2" and some other tags either ...... like when you search for a file and use wildcards like -> test*(means test and other files contains test)... Is it possible to have something like this?

Comment: Dude I found the answer , thanks for your response... the solution is that I have to use find({ tags: { $regex: `${tag}`, $options: "i" } } this in my query . good luck